# Multiplying two data sets and more in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames that have common columns.

```
  # Generate DF1
    set.seed(219)
    x0 <- rnorm(5, 22, 17)
    x2 <- rnorm(5, 44, 15)
    x3 <- rnorm(5, 56, 13)
    x7 <- rnorm(5, 0, 3)
    x9 <- rnorm(5, 28, 31)
    x10 <- rnorm(5, 4, 75)
    x11 <- rnorm(5, 7, 1)
    dat1 <- data.frame(x0,x2,x3,x7,x9, x10, x11)
    dat1$ID1 <- rownames(dat1)

  # Generate DF2
    x1 <- rnorm(10, 2, 19)
    x2 <- rnorm(10, 4, 18)
    x3 <- rnorm(10, 5, 17)
    x4 <- rnorm(10, 7, 16)
    x5 <- rnorm(10, 8, 51)
    x6 <- rnorm(10, 9, 5)
    x7 <- rnorm(10, 0, 3)
    x8 <- rnorm(10, 34, 2)
    x9 <- rnorm(10, 28, 1)
    dat2 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)
    dat2$ID2 <- rownames(dat2)
```

Note that `DF1` has 5 rows while `DF2` has 10 rows. Also, similar columns names in each data frame does not mean that both columns are the same in value.

This is what I would like to do:

1. Since `DF1` has 5 rows, I need to create 5 columns in `DF2` and let's call them `y1, y2, y3, y4, y5`.
2. Here is how to compute `y1`: I need to take the first row in `DF1` and multiply it with similar columns in `DF2` for all the rows.
   The size of `y1`will be (10 rows and 1 column). And I need to calculate the following for each row in DF2.

   y1 = x0 + x2(DF1)*x2(DF2) + x3(DF1)*x3(DF2) + x7(DF1)*x7(DF2) + x9(DF1)*x9(DF2)

Similarly, For y2, we need to start in the second row of DF1 ... Etc.

In terms of vectors and matrices, here is how to compute y1.

Let the first row in DF1 as (x01, x21, x31, x71, x91, x101, x111, ID11). Then first first value of y1 (remember y1 is 10*1):

y11 = x01 + x21(DF1)*x21(DF2) + x31(DF1)*x31(DF2) + x71(DF1)*x71(DF2) + x91(DF1)*x91(DF2).

Second value of y1:

y12 = x01 + x21(DF1)*x22(DF2) + x31(DF1)*x32(DF2) + x71(DF1)*x72(DF2) + x91(DF1)*x92(DF2).

...

finaly, the 10th value of y1 is:

y110  = x01 + x21(DF1)*x210(DF2) + x31(DF1)*x310(DF2) + x71(DF1)*x710(DF2) + x91(DF1)*x910(DF2).

How can I implement my algorithm?

Comment: So, will the `x0` be constant 'y2', 'y3', etc.. i.e. whether the formula differs for 'y2', 'y3', etc

Comment: correct. since DF2 has no x0.... I can add x0 in DF2 as 1's and then do x0(DF1)*x0(DF2).

Comment: also, one more doubt, so the 1st row for 'x2' in DF1 will be multiplied by all rows of 'x2' in 'DF2'?

Comment: x2 in DF1 is a number, and I need to multiply it for each x2 in DF2.

Comment: I have the same doubt/confusion. I think there's something not quite right in the logic here. If we multiplied 1 row of 1 common column from dat1 against all rows of that column in dat2, then the length would be 10x1. However you're talking about *adding* the unique columns of dat1 to the 10x1 products of *all* 4 common columns and I don't know how that could work out to a 10x1 vector. Perhaps you could give a step by step example of the calculations for y1.

Comment: Did you mean to multiply the unique column values (like x0) for a given row against a 10x1 vector of 1's then add all of the 10x1 vectors rowwise?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'll add an example.

Comment: From your initial post, I thought you wanted to create columns in DF1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on my understanding of what you want to do, which I alluded to in a comment.

Basically, for the non-common columns from `dat1` I multiplied them by a vector of ones to get them into a conformable dimension, then added the 10x1 vectors for each `y` (`y1`, etc) row-wise, so that each is a 10x1 vector:

```
common_cols <- intersect(colnames(dat1),colnames(dat2))
uniq_cols   <- setdiff(colnames(dat1),colnames(dat2))
uniq_cols   <- uniq_cols[!uniq_cols=="ID1"]

tmp  <- data.frame(y1=rep(NA,10), y2=rep(NA,10),y3=rep(NA,10),y4=rep(NA,10),y5=rep(NA,10))
tmp1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=10, ncol = 7))

for(i in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  for(j in 1:length(common_cols)){
    tmp1[,j] <-  dat1[i,common_cols[j]] * dat2[,common_cols[j]] 
  }
  for(k in 1:length(uniq_cols)){
    tmp1[,k+4] <- dat1[i,uniq_cols[k]]*rep(1,10)
  }
  tmp[,i] <- rowSums(tmp1)
}
```

The result is:

```
tmp
```

> ```
>          y1          y2        y3        y4         y5
> 1  2796.812   226.31244 1924.2130 4392.7841  1459.8979
> 2  1786.241    17.11732  716.6079 2044.0003   141.6572
> 3  1371.890  -334.09190  324.3946 1578.0200  -262.0858
> 4  1235.717  -446.01583  176.2845 1422.1088  -411.2424
> 5  1995.976  -377.33202 1152.6527 3297.5986   635.7040
> 6  2233.255   197.51252 1155.2367 2847.4433   599.1098
> 7  3437.539  1675.03212 2328.7100 3876.5423  1914.7753
> 8   291.687 -1331.27575 -737.9568  299.7451 -1413.6779
> 9  1659.648  -244.14992  678.3120 2266.3193   144.3870
> 10 1675.775  -532.41657  668.3817 2491.0892    60.3962
> ```

Comment: I manually calculated y11 for the data above (same seed), but I got 2744.334 (not 2796.812). I edited my question to show the exact calculations for y1. Thanks.

Comment: @user9292 Can you look through the logic and tell me where your calculation is different? It should be a trivial change, but right now I'm not sure where the logic differs. If you calculated it in R you can add the code to your question.

Comment: y11 <- 3.3448395+ (33.8937*54.5535477) + (66.85438*-11.412676) + (-2.125617*-2.7894739) + (56.797272*29.03353) = 2744.334.

Comment: I think the glitch is related to the last piece in your code. 1) I did add x0 column in dat2  as 1. 2) tmp1 should have 5 columns not 7 : tmp1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=10, ncol = 5)), and 3) Here is the final code: tmp  <- data.frame(y1=rep(NA,10), y2=rep(NA,10),y3=rep(NA,10),y4=rep(NA,10),y5=rep(NA,10))
tmp1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=10, ncol = 5))

for(i in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  for(j in 1:length(common_cols)){
    tmp1[,j] <-  dat1[i,common_cols[j]] * dat2[,common_cols[j]] 
  }
   tmp[,i] <- rowSums(tmp1)
}

tmp

Answer (score 0):

With a `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach:

```
library(magrittr); library(dplyr)
```

## Generate DF1

```
set.seed(219)
x0 <- rnorm(5, 22, 17)
x2 <- rnorm(5, 44, 15)
x3 <- rnorm(5, 56, 13)
x7 <- rnorm(5, 0, 3)
x9 <- rnorm(5, 28, 31)
x10 <- rnorm(5, 4, 75): i am commenting this out, based on your 
x11 <- rnorm(5, 7, 1): 
dat1 <- data.frame(x0,x2,x3,x7,x9, x10, x11)
# dat1$ID1 <- rownames(dat1) : not yet
```

## Generate DF2

```
x1 <- rnorm(10, 2, 19)
x2 <- rnorm(10, 4, 18)
x3 <- rnorm(10, 5, 17)
x4 <- rnorm(10, 7, 16)
x5 <- rnorm(10, 8, 51)
x6 <- rnorm(10, 9, 5)
x7 <- rnorm(10, 0, 3)
x8 <- rnorm(10, 34, 2)
x9 <- rnorm(10, 28, 1)
dat2 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)
# dat2$ID2 <- rownames(dat2) : not yet
```

## Create the missing vars in dat2

```
dat2$x0 <- 1
newCol <- names(dat1)[!(names(dat1) %in% names(dat2))]
dat2[, names(dat1)[!(names(dat1) %in% names(dat2))]] <- 0
```

## Rownames columns

```
dat1$ID1 <- rownames(dat1)
dat2$ID2 <- rownames(dat2)
```

## form wide to long table

```
df1 <- tidyr::gather(dat1, X, var, -c(ID1))
df2 <- tidyr::gather(dat2, X, var, -c(ID2))
```

## join the two tables

```
df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by="X")
rm(df2)
```

## do your multiplication

```
df1$var <- df1$var.x * df1$var.y
```

## create y columns

```
df1 %<>% group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% summarise(var=sum(var)) %>% ungroup %>% 
  mutate(ID1=paste0("y", ID1)) %>% 
  {left_join(dat2, tidyr::spread(., ID1, var), by="ID2")}
```

## keep relevant columns

```
df1 <- df1[, names(df1)[!(names(df1) %in% newCol)]]

View(df1)
```